# How to break a free drawing into segments in Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I want to have an undo option in Fabric JS. But instead of removing a whole free-drawn line at once, I want to remove it piece by piece. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As paths while drawing are added one by one, you can implement it in a following way (let's assume `app` as root object of the application):

1) Have array of paths, canvas JSON representations and flag that drawing is enabled initialised

```
app.isDrawingMode = false; //should be toggled when you're adding other elements
app.__state = [];
```

2) Subscribe to each path addition in case if it's drawing

```
canvas.on('object:added', function(e) {
  if (app.isDrawingMode && e.target && e.target.path && e.target.path.length) {
    app.saveToHistory();
  }
});

app.saveToHistory = function() {
  var myjson = this.__canvas.toObject();
  this.__state.push(JSON.stringify(myjson));
}
```

3) The undo function

```
app.undo = function() {
  if (app.__state.length > 1) {
    canvas.clear();
    var stateNumber = app.__state.length - 2;
    canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(this.__state[stateNumber]),
    canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    app.__state.splice(-1, 1);
  }
}
```